# How to access dbf file in a client PC from a server using PHP

Tags: php, client-server, dbf, dbase

I need to have read access data to a dbf file stored within a client computer that's connected to my server locally. Is there any way that I can do this using PHP?

The scenario is, when the admin of the site clicks UPDATE on his PC, it tells the server to open the dbf file from another client PC and gets data from it. I have read [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dbase-open.php) but it seems it does not have parameters that allows me to specify the IP address of the client PC.

My idea is to access via IP example: 192.168.1.24 is the IP and the dbf file is in "C:Users\Data\Sales.dbf".

Comment: You can't access a file from a remote machine if they are all running standard browsers. However you could write a browser plugin that uploads this file (once or periodically) to the server, so that a suitably authorised web client can then access it via the server. Or, this could be some automated system like Cron or Task Scheduler.

Comment: Since you are on a LAN, another way to do it would be to specify the IP address of the host. I'm not familiar with DBase, but it would require each computer to be running a DBase server, rather than just containing the .dbf file.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot access another one's computer, obviously for security reasons. You have to upload this file and store it on your server to open it there is no way around that unless you hack your clients.